Control GPU fan in ASUS laptop
After much research and trial and error, I found a way to control some of the fans on an Asus ProArt 15 laptop (ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ProArt StudioBook W500G5T_W500G5T)
I believe this controls the "CPU" fan, which is the fan on the left of the laptop.
I want to control the "GPU" fan on the laptop's right side.
The only reliable way I found to control the left fan was to issue these commands (as root):
turn on fan:
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon7/pwm1_enable

turn off fan:
echo 2 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon7/pwm1_enable

However, this doesn't control the right fan, which I believe is the GPU fan, which is stuck at a low speed (the GPU is usually at 95 Celsius).
Is there an equivalent command to control the other GPU fan that is on the right side?
These are the other files I see in the same directory:
$ ls /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/hwmon/hwmon7/
device  fan1_input  fan1_label  fan2_input  fan2_label  name  power  pwm1_enable  pwm2_enable  subsystem  uevent

pwm2_enable seems to do the same as pwm1_enable, i.e. control the left fan.
fan1_input  fan1_label  fan2_input  fan2_label seems only to contain fan names and the current RPM.
The GPU in this system is Quadro RTX 5000 with Max-Q Design with driver 535.171.04.

This is the information showing in nvidia-smi. Fan appears as N/A (?).
Wed Apr 17 16:42:37 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.171.04             Driver Version: 535.171.04   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro RTX 5000 with Max...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   79C    P0              80W /  80W |   5559MiB / 16384MiB |     63%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3014      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                         3054MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3317      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        344MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4437      G   ...irefox/4033/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      587MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    910464      G   ...erProcess --variations-seed-version      421MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A   1447430      G   ...yNGRmOTA1YjMwZDQ%3D&browser=firefox      149MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A   1447493      G   ...rkService --variations-seed-version        3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A   2932062      G   ...yOnDemand --variations-seed-version      194MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A   3634216      G   ./steamwebhelper                              3MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

These are some of the pages in nvidia-settings:




EDIT:
According to https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-set-fanspeed-in-linux-from-terminal/72705/19
this should have worked, but it doesn't, I guess that the fan doesn't "belong" to the GPU and it always run at the same speed:
$ sudo nvidia-settings -a GPUFanControlState=1 -a GPUTar
getFanSpeed=60

  Attribute 'GPUFanControlState' (proart:1[gpu:0]) assigned value 1.


ERROR: Error resolving target specification '' (No targets match target
       specification), specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=60'.


is the fan information showing up in the nvidia control panel or nvidia-smi?

@rtaft , see update

are you certain there are 2 fans?  Not a shared one for both the CPU and GPU?

@rtaft yes, As far as I can tell the laptop has two fans (left and right) that are visible. and the Freon app, shows too values, one (GPU) is stuck to a low velocity and I can feel it rotating rather slowly. see the edit. The command sensors return asus-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter cpu_fan:     7400 RPM gpu_fan:     4200 RPM

Those are the actual values returned?  7400 and 4200 even?  That doesn't seem realistic, especially since 4200 is not slow, and 7400 seems a bit high.  Does the bios let you configure any fan profiles?

yes, these are the numbers. Even if I don’t trust the numbers, i know that the GPU fan can go faster (in Windows it does) I don’t see an option in the BIOS, although it reports the current speeds.

I checked the BIOS and it dynamically reports the CPU fan (only), it reads an number around 3800 (after staring the BIOS) so it seems realistic.

@rtaft, this is the most promising info I could find,  https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-set-fanspeed-in-linux-from-terminal/72705/19 , but still didn't work. See my edit.
